# Why are Rankin-Selberg convolutions different when $n=m$?

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Let $\pi$ an automorphic cuspidal representation on $GL_n(\mathbb{A})$ (and similarly $\pi'$ on $GL_m$). For $m=n-1$, it is standard to introduce the Rankin-Selberg L-function as (the gcd of the integrals)
$$I(s,\phi, \phi') = \int_{[GL_m]} \phi \begin{pmatrix} h & \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} \phi'(h) |\det h|^{s-1/2} dh$$
where $\phi$ is here understood as a certain, explicit, projection of $\phi$ on $GL_{m+1}$. In particular, we recover the classical L-function for $GL_2$ in the case $ m+1 = n =2$, where classically
$$L(s,f) = \int_0^\infty f(iy) y^s \frac{dy}{y}.$$

I would like to understand what breaks when $n=m$, why we don't consider
$$\int_{[GL_n]} \phi(h) \phi'(h) |\det h|^{s-1/2} dh$$
but rather a twist by a certain Eisenstein series
$$\int_{[GL_n]} \phi(g) \phi'(g) E(g,s, \Phi) dg$$
for a certain Schwartz function $\Phi$. Is it due to converge issue or is it there a deeper reason to twist this case compared to the previous one? And how natural is it to do so with an Eisenstein series?

Comment: Your definition of $I(s,\phi,\phi')$ is incorrect when $m < n - 1$; there is also a unipotent average. In any case, you should read one of Cogdell's surveys on $L$-functions. The main idea is that we want our integral of automorphic forms to be *Eulerian*: it should factorise as a product over local places of local integrals, each of which represents the local $L$-function of interest. The integral you propose is not Eulerian.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thanks for your answer. I edited to avoid adding too much notations, and restricted to the case $m=n-1$. The core of my misunderstanding remains: how can I see that we need such an Eisenstein series, with this Schwartz function, in the case $n=m$? This questions comes from my reading of Cogdell's notes.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with Rankin-Selberg integrals involving integrals of automorphic forms, we want these integrals to be *Eulerian*. That is, such an integral should *factorise* as a product over all places $v$ of the underlying number field $F$. This factorisation should involve integrals of the *local* components of this automorphic form, and each of these local integrals should represent the local component of the associated Rankin-Selberg $L$-function.

---

Let us see how this works for the $\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_n$ Rankin-Selberg integral. The integral of interest is
$$\int\limits_{\mathrm{Z}_n(\mathbb{A}) \mathrm{GL}_n(F) \backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})} \varphi_{\pi}(g) \varphi_{\sigma}(g) E(g,s;\Phi,\omega_{\pi}\omega_{\sigma}) \, dg.$$
Here $\mathrm{Z}_n$ denotes the centre of $\mathrm{GL}_n$, $\varphi_{\pi}$ and $\varphi_{\sigma}$ are automorphic forms lying in automorphic representations $\pi$ and $\sigma$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})$ with central characters $\omega_{\pi}$ and $\omega_{\sigma}$, and $E(g,s;\Phi,\omega)$ is the Eisenstein series on $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})$ associated to a Schwartz function $\Phi \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{A}^n)$ and a character $\omega$.

Note that as stated, the integral cannot immediately be written as a product of local integrals, since it is not over the adelic points $G(\mathbb{A})$ of some group $G$ due to the fact that we are modding out on the left by the discrete subgroup $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$.

Nonetheless, by unfolding the integral via the fact that Eisenstein series are averages over $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$, we find that this integral is equal to
$$\int\limits_{\mathrm{N}_n(\mathbb{A}) \backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})} W_{\varphi_{\pi}}(g) W_{\varphi_{\sigma}}(g) \Phi(e_n g) \left|\det g\right|_{\mathbb{A}}^s \, dg.$$
Here $\mathrm{N}_n$ is the upper triangular unipotent subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n$, while
$$W_{\varphi}(g) = \int\limits_{\mathrm{N}_n(F) \backslash \mathrm{N}_n(\mathbb{A})} \varphi(ug) \overline{\psi_n}(u) \, du$$
is the Whittaker function associated to an automorphic form $\varphi$. The payoff is that the global integral is over the adelic points $G(\mathbb{A})$ of $G = \mathrm{N}_n \backslash \mathrm{GL}_n$. Moreover, the integrand is *factorisable* if the Whittaker functions $W_{\varphi_{\pi}}$ and $W_{\varphi_{\sigma}}$ and the Schwartz function $\Phi$ are chosen to be factorisable:
$$W_{\varphi_{\pi}}(g) = \prod_v W_{\varphi_{\pi},v}(g_v), \qquad W_{\varphi_{\sigma}}(g) = \prod_v W_{\varphi_{\sigma},v}(g_v), \qquad \Phi(x) = \prod_v \Phi_v(x_v).$$
Here $W_{\varphi_{\pi},v}$ and $W_{\varphi_{\sigma},v}$ are *local* Whittaker functions from $\mathrm{GL}_n(F_v)$ to $\mathbb{C}$, while $\Phi_v$ is a *local* Schwartz function from $F_v^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$. (Whittaker functions and Schwartz functions that are factorisable in this way are called pure tensors, and pure tensors span the space of all such Whittaker functions or Schwartz functions.)

Thus the global $\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_n$ Rankin-Selberg integral has the factorisation
$$\prod_v \int\limits_{\mathrm{N}_n(F_v) \backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(F_v)} W_{\varphi_{\pi},v}(g_v) W_{\varphi_{\sigma},v}(g_v) \Phi_v(e_n g_v) \left|\det g_v\right|_v^s \, dg_v.$$
Each local integral represents $L(s,\pi_v \times \sigma_v)$, the local component of the global (completed) Rankin-Selberg $L$-function $\Lambda(s,\pi \times \sigma)$.

---

What about other integrals of automorphic forms? If we instead study something like
$$\int\limits_{\mathrm{GL}_n(F) \backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})} \varphi_{\pi}(g) \varphi_{\sigma}(g) \left|\det g\right|_{\mathbb{A}}^s \, dg,$$
then several things go wrong. Firstly, there is no reason for this to be Eulerian: this cannot be written as an integral over the adelic points of a group $G$ of factorisable Whittaker functions. Secondly, it turns out that this integral need not converge. Thirdly, it also turns out that even if this integral converges, it is zero unless $\widetilde{\pi} \cong \sigma \otimes \left|\det\right|_{\mathbb{A}}^s$, since it defines an invariant pairing.

So you can think of the presence of the Eisenstein series in the $\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_n$ Rankin-Selberg integral as a mitigating factor that ensures that the integral is Eulerian. For $\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_{n - 1}$ Rankin-Selberg integrals, you don't need this, since you can just insert the Fourier-Whittaker expansions of the underlying automorphic forms to get an Eulerian integral. However, this approach doesn't work for the integral
$$\int\limits_{\mathrm{GL}_n(F) \backslash \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})} \varphi_{\pi}(g) \varphi_{\sigma}(g) \left|\det g\right|_{\mathbb{A}}^s \, dg,$$
as can easily be checked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to understand the reasons of your last comment: why inserting the Fourier expansions of the automorphic forms in the integral would not work *exactly* in the $GL_n \times GL_n$ case, but would otherwise?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better answer than trying it yourself: see what happens when you insert the Fourier expansion.